# Android MediaRecorder IllegalStateException prepare method

Tags: android, mediarecorder

```
private void dispatchTakeVideo() throws InterruptedException {

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
             + "/balloon_launch/" +  System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".3gp";
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setMaxDuration(3600); 
    recorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);
    recorder.setVideoFrameRate(15); 
    Thread.sleep(10000); 
    try {
            recorder.prepare();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Recording","prepare() failed");
        }
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    recorder.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

I am trying to programmatically launch a video recording in my application, however, I am having difficulty getting the media recorder to work. I am getting an illegal state exception, and after debugging, I know the prepare() method is causing the problem for me... Several people have suggested on other questions similar to use the Thread.sleep() so I have included several places, but that isnt working either...I have included the method for the video, the logcat, and the permissions in the comments below..I am wondering if it has to do with the fact that I havnt done anything in the xml for the activity and the reason for this is that I dont want to show the video I record on the screen, I just want it to record at a certain time... Thanks for any help.

Here is the Log Cat

```
11-22 11:14:38.327: E/Trace(795): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-22 11:14:39.007: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 51K, 3% free 8055K/8259K, paused      35ms, total 37ms
11-22 11:14:39.027: I/dalvikvm-heap(795): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.743MB for 1918240-  byte allocation
11-22 11:14:39.097: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 3% free 9927K/10183K, paused  24ms+5ms, total 71ms
11-22 11:14:39.387: D/gralloc_goldfish(795): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-22 11:14:52.650: E/Recording(795): prepare() failed
11-22 11:14:57.653: E/MediaRecorder(795): start called in an invalid state: 4
11-22 11:14:57.653: D/AndroidRuntime(795): Shutting down VM
11-22 11:14:57.656: W/dalvikvm(795): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception      (group=0x40a13300)
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795): java.lang.IllegalStateException
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native  Method)
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at  com.finding.videoing.sharing.MainActivity.dispatchTakeVideoIntent(MainActivity.java:148)
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at   com.finding.videoing.sharing.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:129)
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at    com.finding.videoing.sharing.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:61)
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at    android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at     android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at       java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-22 11:14:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native  Method)
```

Comment: did u add the permission......

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
 </uses-permission>

Comment: these are all the permissions I have in the Manifest right now